# How good is Python secrets.SystemRandom in Windows 10?

Tags: python, random, cryptography

I want to use Python for basic cryptographic applications with Windows 10.

I see that [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) uses [secrets.SystemRandom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) which in turn uses [os.urandom()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) for random number generation.

How good is os.urandom in Windows 10?

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) I see that os.urandom() in Windows uses CryptGenRandom() which is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) by Microsoft and has some security flaws as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom).

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, partially yes, I just dont know what to do with the answer. Is CryptGenRandom() really being used or the python documentation is outdated? If CryptGenRandom() is still being used, is it a big deal? Wikipedia does not mention windows 10, microsoft does not mention why it should not be used....

Comment: Wikipedia says the flaw was fixed in XP SP3 and never existed from Vista from what I can see. As to whether the Python docs are out of date I don't know - it's not impossible, you'd have to look at the actual implementation to find out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the OP's point remains: the question remains unanswered.

Comment: @NicSzerman if anything it's even more answered, from the Python end at least; the docs now say that this _"Changed in version 3.11: On Windows, `BCryptGenRandom()` is used instead of `CryptGenRandom()` which is deprecated."_

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's not answered in this post, it's new information you're bringing now. Feel free to actually post an answer below if you think it's good enough.